# How to convert .wfs files into .csv

Tags: python, windows, csv, export-to-csv

I have thousands of .wfs(windows script files) files and I am looking for a solution to help me convert this huge amount of .wfs files into .csv files using Python Anaconda or Spyder.

May I know any IO API similar to pandas where could read wfs files using similar functions like read.excel? or does python read script files?

Or could I convert these script files into Excel read quick (I know how to convert excel files into csv using Python)?

An example .wfs along with the converted csv is contained in the link below:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uwbajpubzuxn7g5/AABbD7W4pXFlxiIi1UAlHKTFa?dl=0

Comment: Did you mean `wsf`?

Comment: I guess you could just read these wsf files and write the contents to csv files? Probably easier said than done. I know that wsf files follow XML structure, so it might be possible to use an python XML API such as [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Comment: I cannot understand. I would expect a wsf file to contain scripts composed of instructions. A csv file is composed of lines containing fields. What kind of conversion do you want? An example could help (content of a wsf file along with what you want the csv to be)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a small sample wsf file and what your expected output CSV file would look like for that file.

Comment: @MartinEvans I have uploaded an example file for your reference. Thank you

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have uploaded an example file in the dropbox link provided. TQ

Comment: The WFS file has a binary format? What application creates it?

Comment: An acoustic emission data logger creates the wfs files. @MartinEvans

Comment: With the exact model number and product name it might be possible to search for more information regarding the format of your file.